# how to add dyanamic form fields with unique name in angular js

Tags: angularjs

i have a form in that I added fields dynamically , but when i try to get the unique name it's not working, anyone  can help me thanks in advance. Find the below my code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Angular Forms | Form2 </title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
 <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
 <script src="js/app2.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>
 <div ng-app="myApp2" ng-controller="myCtrl2">
 <div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-2">
    <form name="form1" ng-submit="submitForm2()" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <!--for adding extra fields  data-->
        {{count}}
        <fieldset  data-ng-repeat="choice in choices"  ng-init="count=0">

         <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <label class="col-md-2">Skills</label>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="skills"  ng-focus="userskills_msg=true" ng-model="user2.skills" placeholder="Enter your skills" />
                        <p ng-show="errorSkill">{{errorSkill}}</p>
                    </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3"> <span ng-cloak ng-show="userskills_msg"> please choose your location</span> </div> 
                <button class="remove" ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeChoice()">-</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        </fieldset>
        <!--end adding extra fields data-->
  <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="add_emp" ng-click="addfields()">+add another employment</a><!--<button class="addfields" ng-click="addfields()">Add fields</button>--> </div>

        </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   </div>

   </body>
   </html>
```

i am initialise a variable using ng-init and i incremented that value in controller value is incrementd but i a not geeting unique names and the file dis not displaying

```
var sampleApp = angular.module("myApp2", []);

sampleApp.controller("myCtrl2", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.addfields = function () {
        var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length + 1;
        $scope.count = newItemNo;
        console.log(count);
        console.log(newItemNo);
        $scope.choices.push({
            'id' : 'choice' + newItemNo
        });
    };

    $scope.removeChoice = function () {
        var lastItem = $scope.choices.length - 1;
        $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
    };
});
```

Comment: how is this question related to PHP ?

Comment: You are missing a form closing tag and your link header is not terminated.

Answer (score 0):

This is your [code working on plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/wkX581HxeewZ1zNczHW9?p=info).

```js
var sampleApp = angular.module("myApp2", []);

sampleApp.controller("myCtrl2", function ($scope, $http) {
  
    $scope.choices = [];
    $scope.count = 0;
  
    $scope.addfields = function () {
        var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length + 1;
        
        $scope.count = newItemNo;
        console.log($scope.count);
        
        var item = {};
        
        item.id = "choice" + newItemNo;
        
        $scope.choices.push(item);
    };

    $scope.removeChoice = function () {
        var lastItem = $scope.choices.length - 1;
        $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="controller.js"></script>
      
   </head>
   <body>
      <div ng-app="myApp2" ng-controller="myCtrl2">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-2">
               <form name="form1" ng-submit="submitForm2()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
               {{count}}
               <fieldset  data-ng-repeat="choice in choices"  ng-init="count=0">
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-md-2">Skills</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="skills"  ng-focus="userskills_msg=true" ng-model="user2.skills" placeholder="Enter your skills" />
                           <p ng-show="errorSkill">{{errorSkill}}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3"> <span ng-cloak ng-show="userskills_msg"> please choose your location</span> </div>
                        <button type="button" class="remove" ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeChoice()">Remove Choice</button>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </fieldset>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                     <button type="button" class="addfields" ng-click="addfields()">Add fields</button>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

You have forgotten to initialize the necessary variables to function properly

```
$scope.choices=[];
$scope.count=0;
```

And some bad references, example `console.log(count);` Should be `console.log ($ scope.count);`

Comment: thanks for the reply, with the above code after adding two fields.. the data which i am entered in that fields is not getting in post parameters after submitting the form